# Install Newtonsoft for unity .net 3.5 version

Tags: c#, json.net, install.packages

I need Newtonsoft to get things work with playfab, they have great sample which uses Newtonsoft and does almost every thing I want in my game.

But I can't install it using visual studio -> Tools -> NUget package manager -> Package manager console.

I use the following command: "Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 3.5.8"

And this is what I get to see:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 3.5.8
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Newtonsoft.Json.3.5.8' with respect to project 'Game.CSharp', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Subset v3.5'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Newtonsoft.Json.3.5.8' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Newtonsoft.Json.3.5.8'
Resolved actions to install package 'Newtonsoft.Json.3.5.8'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.3.5.8 : ' does not exist in project 'Game.CSharp'
Removing package 'Newtonsoft.Json.3.5.8 : ' from folder 'C:\Users\\Documents\Game\packages'
Removed package 'Newtonsoft.Json.3.5.8 : ' from folder 'C:\Users\\Documents\Game\packages'
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 3.5.8'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Subset v3.5', but the 
package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 3.5.8
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Can somebody help me the right direction,
Thanks in advance

Comment: "'.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Subset v3.5', but the 
package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author." >> Have you contacted James from Newtonsoft? http://www.newtonsoft.com/contact

Comment: No I haven't contacted him, sorry I didn't see that point. I will take contact with him. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PlayFab C# and Unity SDKs no longer require Newtonsoft.Json.  We've put a modified implementation of SimpleJson into both SDKs, to allow for more customization and control on our end.

You can use Newtonsoft.Json if you need to, and we support hot-swapping out the Json parser, but we provide better support for our latest implementation.

We don't check Stack Overflow for unanswered questions regularly, so feel free to post these questions on our own forums for a faster reply:
https://community.playfab.com/index.html